# foreach result only first letters of each row

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im getting the array from a function then using it on a foreach, it prints all rows, how can i print specific row when im using [0] after array it displays only first letters of both rows.

PHP FUNCTION:

```
    public function selectedOffer($model_id){
    $qq = mysqli_query($this->connection,"SELECT offerId FROM offers WHERE model_id='$model_id' ORDER BY id ASC");
    $results = array();


    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($qq)) {
    $results[] = $result;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

FOREACH PHP

```
    foreach ($mUser->selectedOffer($modelid) as $key) {
    echo $key['offerId'][0];
}
```

also when i remove the [0] it prints both rows.
My question is how to print the first or second or which row i want?

Comment: can you show structure of the result print_r($results) ?

Comment: I agree with Deadman, include an array in your question. I'm quite sure there is answers that does not require looping at all that might interest you.

Comment: I've just updated to this:
$data = $mUser->selectedOffer($modelid);
  echo $data[0]["offerId"];

and it worked, Thank you.

Comment: Ok? And what is that an answer to? Both comments above ask for the array structure and you answer with how you get the data variable.

Comment: Here you have it:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => test1 [offerId] => test1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => TEST1 [offerId] => TEST1 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get specific/ first row,s column

```
  $data = $mUser->selectedOffer($modelid);
  echo $data[0]["offerId"];
```

And all rows column

```
   foreach ($data as $key) {
        echo $key['offerId'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode and array_column to echo a complete array column in one line of code:

```
echo implode("", array_column($yourarray, "offerId"));
```

The first argument of the implode is what should join the items in the array.
Your and the accepted answer has nothing that is why it's `""`, but it can be replaced with say: `"<br>\n"` if you want new line between each item of the array.